# copy a zip file from external server to my server

Tags: php, html

i would like to copy a zip-file from an external server to the directory where the script run.

for example:

```
$thezipfile = "http://www.yxz.com/user/login/userid/1234/password/1234/page/L2V4cG9ydC9kb3dubG9hZC90L01RPT0vYy9NZz09Lw=";
```

This doesnt work (download.php):

```
$save = file_put_contents('newfile.zip',$thezipfile);
```

after that, there is a file on my server called 'newfile.zip', but...its empty!??

Comment: A string containing a URL is just a string. You're never actually downloading anything, you're just passing a string around. Use curl or `file_get_contents` to actually download the data from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You have not got any file contents to put into the new file.

You would need to `file_get_contents($thezipfile)` before you `file_put_contents()`

Comment: this works, but only if the string is "www.xyz.com/file.zip" ! Its not working with "http://www.yxz.com/user/login/L2V4cG9ydC9kb3dubG9hZC90L01RPT0vYy9NZz09Lw="

Comment: Firstly, there is no Of Course about it, as you did not give that information in your question, we have no way of knowing it, or if you have tried that. You will need to check the log files on the server that has the file to see why it is not working then as you going to that page is the same as php requesting that page. You may also want to check that they are the same. xyz.com is NOT necessarily the same as www.xyz.com

Comment: ok ok! i cannot check the log files on the server from our supplier. The problem is the URI and i have no idea how it works with this adress. ".ZIP" in adress works, but "../werjwrHEfjh" doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually read the external file before saving.  Change your second line to

```
file_put_contents('newfile.zip',file_get_contents($thezipfile));
```

Comment: the problem is the string. "www.xyz.com/file.zip" works, but "www.xyz.com/file/page/L2V4cG9ydC9kb3dubG9hZC90=" doesn't work!